# Breakable tcolorbox broken inside minipage

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, minipage, texlive-2020

I have a breakable tcolorbox inside of a minipage (is there a counter indication for this?).

When the minipage goes to the next page, it gets broken.

The error message is :

```
(line 23) The upper box part has become overfull
```

Outside of the minipage, no problem. Non-breakable tcolorbox, no problem either. Minipage on the first page, works fine too.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    left side
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Text here   
        \begin{itemize}
            \item list item here
            \item and here
            \item and here
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    Text here   
    \begin{itemize}
        \item list item here
        \item and here
        \item and here
    \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using XeTeX on TL2020 Vanilla.

tcolorbox is v4.42.

Where am I missing something?

Regards,

Ivan

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481441/how-do-i-make-the-page-break-occur-in-the-following-document-with-minipage-and

Comment: `tcolorbox` does give you a warning that things have gone wrong, so I suspect you're not missing anything.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250616/minipages-across-page-breaks

Comment: @jsbibra this is minipage inside tcolorbox. I am doing the other way around, tcolorbox inside minipage. It is not the same or is it?

Comment: @DavidPurton I forgot the error message, I edited my post. I don't understand it.

Comment: Using a breakable `tcolorbox` inside of a `minipage` which in turn can not break across pages does not really make sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What type of contents will "left side"  contain? text, images, something entirely different? Do you also want that part to break across pages?

Comment: @jsbibra my tcolorbox is breakable but very small and it does not run accross pages. Once again, the box is inside the minipage and not the opposite. I don't get the link with these other posts.

Comment: @leandriis Yes, you're right, and that would be a solution. I have a generic « example » box which is breakable. And for some short examples, I am using it side by side with the text of the lesson. It works fine two times before one crashes in my doc. I could create another non-breakable box of course, but got curious for the reason behind. Left part is just text, nothing weird there.

Comment: @Ivan, presumably `tcolorbox` is just confused about trying to break inside a non-breaking environment and can't do it. I would either try and avoid the `minipage`s all together and just use `tcolorbox`es or ask a more specific question: How can I tell if my `tcolorbox` is in a `minipage` and if it is then set its `breakable` option to `false`?

Comment: @DavidPurton [Good idea!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588297/change-tcolorbox-option-when-inside-a-minipage)

Comment: For the record: solved in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588297/change-tcolorbox-option-when-inside-a-minipage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the are two mistakes, the first one is declaring `\tcbset{breakable}` which makes all boxes breakables. And the second declaring the `tcolorbox` inside a `minipage` when you can use `width` option to adjust tcolorbox width, `nofeboreafter` to declare it without moving to a new paragraph  and `box align` to decide how to align the box with surrounding text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
%\tcbset{breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.4\textwidth, nobeforeafter]
        Text here   
        \begin{itemize}
            \item list item here
            \item and here
            \item and here
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}
    Text here   
    \begin{itemize}
        \item list item here
        \item and here
        \item and here
    \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `width` + `nobeforeafter` solution is nice but the thing is, most of my boxes need to be breakable and I'd like to take care as less as possible of any special case. As mentionned in the [other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588297/change-tcolorbox-option-when-inside-a-minipage), there is a solution which takes care of setting the `breakable` option to `false` when needed. Do you think I shoud have two boxes, one for the split case and another one for the non-split case?

Comment: @Ivan Let me insist that you don't need to use the `tcolorbox` inside a minipage. You know when you want a `minipage`, then, beside it you will always add an unbreakable and narrow `tcolorbox` because the minipage is unbreakable. How to do it is a matter of taste. You can declare two different `\newtcolorbox`, one breakable and another unbreakable or just declare one kind of box (breakable if you prefer) and add the option `unbreakable` (and `width`) when it's beside a `minipage`. If `minipage` width is constant, you can declare a `tcbset` style with `width+unbreakable` and avoid some typing.

Comment: @Ivan By the way, you could even avoid the `minipage` if you use the `paracol` package. With it you can organize the text in two parallel columns. The text on one column and the tcolorbox on the other. In this case you don't have to worry because text and tcolorbox will break as usual. An example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533298/1952

Comment: I got your point. You're right, I should not surround the `tcolorbox` with a `minipage`. I still get some small alignment issues but it has nothing to do with this question. Thank you.