# Change tcolorbox option when inside a minipage

Tags: tcolorbox, minipage

Following [David Purton advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588293/breakable-tcolorbox-broken-inside-minipage):

I have a `tcolorbox` which may run accross pages, thus it is set as breakable.

But I sometimes use it inside `minipage` and it gets broken (presumably as `minipage` are not breakable) even when not running accross pages.

The question is: how can I check if my `tcolorbox` is inside a `minipage` and set its breakable option to false?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    left side
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Text here   
        \begin{itemize}
            \item list item here
            \item and here
            \item and here
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    Text here   
    \begin{itemize}
        \item list item here
        \item and here
        \item and here
    \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think my answer in your previous question can avoid this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588420/1952

Comment: I think this one is still relevant as it allows one box setup to cover all needs. After all, `breakable` means "can be split" and not "will be split", no? But for sure, the `width` and `nobeforeafter` parameters are a possible solution. Thank you for that.

Comment: For the record: Ignasi comment answer to the previous question has been accepted as it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set `\tcbset{breakable=false}` inside the `minipage` with bad breaks. For example:

```
 \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
  \tcbset{breakable=false}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
   Text here   
   \begin{itemize}
    \item list item here
    \item and here
    \item and here
   \end{itemize}
  \end{tcolorbox}
```

You can get the same result with:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable=false]
...
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Better, you can set it globally with:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \pretocmd{\minipage}{\tcbset{breakable=false}}{}{}
```

or without `etoolbox`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\minipage{%
 \tcbset{breakable=false}%
 \@ifnextchar[%]
 \@iminipage
 {\@iiiminipage c\relax[s]}}
\makeatother
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\minipage}{\tcbset{breakable=false}}{}{}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-5]
 
 \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  left side
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
   Text here   
   \begin{itemize}
    \item list item here
    \item and here
    \item and here
   \end{itemize}
  \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{minipage}
 
 \begin{tcolorbox}
  Text here   
  \begin{itemize}
   \item list item here
   \item and here
   \item and here
  \end{itemize}
 \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to check twice that you were not me as I did not remember knowing the solution and posting it. Maybe I should get some sleep now :) Thank you Ivan, I take the `etoolbox` solution.

Comment: You can avoid `etoolbox` if you do not use it for other purposes as well. I edited the answer adding another solution.